# Can't select dropdown selector button on webpage which launches popup I think?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm trying to navigate a page which has a dropdown button.  I manage to at least find the dropdown button by using the following code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Real')]").click()
```

This results in an error message though:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
> element not interactable

Here is the full source page:

```
<et-select _ngcontent-mhs-c11="" automation-id="menu-layout-link-mode" class="i-menu-link-mode-demo dropdown-menu no-arrow ng-tns-c13-0 ng-star-inserted" _nghost-mhs-c13="">
    <div _ngcontent-mhs-c13="" class="ng-tns-c13-0">
       <et-select-header _ngcontent-mhs-c11="" _nghost-mhs-c14="">
          <div _ngcontent-mhs-c14="" class="header-text"> Real </div>
          <i _ngcontent-mhs-c14="" class="arrow-down"></i>
       </et-select-header>
       <!---->
    </div>
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!---->
</et-select>
```

I can't get this to actually launch the next bit, which looks like it's auto generated, and I'll have to select next (I haven't written this yet, because I can't see it:

```
<div _ngcontent-mhs-c13="" class="relative-body ng-tns-c13-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-openClose ng-star-inserted"><!---->
    <div _ngcontent-mhs-c13="" class="dlg elad ng-tns-c13-0 ng-star-inserted" style="">
        <div _ngcontent-mhs-c13="" class="dlg-head">
            <span _ngcontent-mhs-c13="" class="icon-close"></span>
        </div>
         <!---->
         <div _ngcontent-mhs-c13="" class="dlg-body"><et-select-body _ngcontent-mhs-c11="" _nghost-mhs-c15=""><et-select-body-option _ngcontent-mhs-c11="" class="active" _nghost-mhs-c16=""><span _ngcontent-mhs-c11="">Real Portfolio</span><!----></et-select-body-option><et-select-body-option _ngcontent-mhs-c11="" class="active" _nghost-mhs-c16=""><span _ngcontent-mhs-c11="">Virtual Portfolio</span><!----><span _ngcontent-mhs-c11="" class="icon-check ng-star-inserted"></span></et-select-body-option></et-select-body>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As kind of a workaround, I tried recording it via the selenium IDE, and using the xpaths in there, but I'm not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute click via javascript and execute_script driver function, like:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='header-text' and contains(text(), 'Real')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: I implemented it like this:
    try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Real')]")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    except Exception:
        print(f'failure is {sys.exc_info()}')

it just fails silently without doing anything?  I'm on windows 10, not sure if I'm missing some sort of installation

Comment: @vwdewaal so, it find the element

Comment: ah ok, I can't see the click happening though, I'll go ahead and try implementing the next bit and see if it can find that

Answer (score 0):

It seems element is not visible before you have interacted. Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable()`

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(), 'Real')]"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: I wrapped that in a try except statement and the error from it was: failure is (<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException'>, TimeoutException('', None, None), <traceback object at 0x000001E7E117E380>)

Comment: @vwdewaal : Is webpage accessible?

Comment: Yeah, it sits there waiting for the 20 seconds.  It immediately renders and then waits.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different locator. Selecting by text is not always reliable. If there are a few locators with the same address, let me know:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((SelectBy.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'header-text')]")))
driver.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'header-text')]").click()
```

Or with CSS locators,

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((SelectBy.CSS_SELECTOR, ".header-text")))
driver.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".header-text").click()
```